# Why do new games need new graphics cards?

Tags: graphics-card, computer-building

PC games from 2013 barely look any different from PC games in 2017. Why don't game developers use the same coding styles and guidelines from a previous time to today's. Why do they need better GPUs and RAM? A top of the top 2013 nvidia GPU is unable to play triple A games from today. Why must we always upgrade our systems when the way the games looks are barely any different?

Comment: "Why don't game developers use the same coding styles and guidelines from a previous time to today's." - Because then every game release in 2017 would look like a game released in 2013.  "Why do they need better GPUs and RAM?" -  Because game engines are being improved, which means the requirements to run them change, which means better hardware is required.  "Why must we always upgrade our systems when the way the games looks are barely any different?" - This is an opinion and does not reflect reality.  I can tell the difference between a game release in 2013 and 2017 by a single screenshot.

Comment: On a personal note, you have asked two extremely offtopic questions within an hour timespan, you might want to review our help center to avoid being question banned.

Comment: I think the impression that the games of today aren't better than the games of the past is similar to how people have the impression that modern movies don't have great special effects like movies of the past did. We're just not impressed by the effects any more because we're spoiled. We now expect near perfection and many barely notice the improvements.

Comment: The look in graphics is not the only thing that changes. Its also the amount of objects being applied at the same time, the effects such as shadow, light, raytracing, reflection, etc... they are the things that costs lots of calculation power.

Comment: Yes. Volumetric lighting, anti-aliasing, and particle physics (like I mentioned in my answer) are all fairly taxing on a lower-end GPU.

Comment: I dispute the claim that games from 4 years ago do not look different from games of today. I'm sure there are individual examples where the differences are minimal, but if you compare the games that were top-of-class then and top-of-class now, there are obvious and significant differences.

Comment: I very much agree, but the point of this site is not to dispute claims, but give answers, and I'm attempting to answer this for OP. Regardless of if (s)he wants to listen, I still would like to make an effort to help. I appreciate your input.

Comment: @Ramhound, thanks for answering my question. I was really curious on why people always upgraded their systems for new games without a second thought. I  was ready to jump to the PC bandwagon but I think the console consistency is better for me since I can always play new games without upgrading my gpu.

Comment: @answerSeeker - You would be hard pressed to tell the difference between a console game released in 2013 compared to one release in 2017 unless you regonized the game itself or it was on a different generation of console all together.

Comment: @answerSeeker Please mark an answer or somehow note that this is answered so people searching at a glance won't waste their time.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

New game engines are written to be compatible with newer versions of graphics interfaces like DirectX or Vulkan.

These newer versions may have poor compatibility with older cards. When new graphics options come out, like SSAO, and other new arrivals, they require more computing power. These make the games look better. What you may be talking about is the fact that at lower settings, newer games look like older games when they were at their highest settings. For instance, particle physics, anti-aliasing, and volumetric lighting are all highly taxing things. If you try running new games at their highest settings when you used to run your old ones at the highest settings, you won't get the same performance, or anywhere near it, for most games.

Comment: You are on the right track, except for the fact, DX and OpenGL ( and/or Vulkan/Mantle) hasn't changed that much in a few years.  Besides DX12 being released in 2014 and Vulkan being released in 2016 those frameworks are stable.  While there are major differences between DX12/Vulkan and DX11/OpenGL, most of those differences, are hardware dependent.  So most of the changes is directly to the amount of processing power GPUs have, which simply means, more computations can be done in a given frame and specifically how many frames can be generated in a given second.

Comment: I gotcha. I know that the big thing that matters in this is the rendering and how each new version of proprietary driver handles rendering with each interface. When you have more effects, and want a prettier outcome, it's going to be harder for your GPU to output so many frames, so fast. If the GPU is more efficient or faster, it will perform much better. Thanks for clarifying my post, @Ramhound. You seem to know much more about this than I.

Comment: Nvidia/AMD have been cheating the better half of a decade, by releasing optimizations for their drivers for specific programs, because those programs are so poorly written in general.  Outside of that it comes down to the computational power of a GPU.  While certain hardware features, of specific versions of DX and OpenGL are impressive, they also have not changed that much in a few years.  The current computational problem in the industry, is 4K resolution, at a stable 60 FPS or higher (sometimes even at 120 Hz).

Comment: @varfirstName Basically new software tech incompatible with old hardware, rendering them outdated. Got it.

Comment: @answerSeeker - The new software technolgy is compatible with the old hardware, the old harware just isn't as powerful, as the newer hardware.  Every GPU instruction, comes at a cost, older hardware can only do some many instructions per second.

Comment: Sort of. If my answer has satisfied your curiosity, don't forget to mark it as your solution. @Ramhound answers this perfectly.